# HttpServletRequest inputstream empty on Weblogic 10.3

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I'm using the **Apache Commons FileUpload** to receive file uploads. The below method works fine for all of the application servers tested, including Weblogic 12.1.3, except for Weblogic 10.3.6.

The `parseRequest` method is returning an empty list which indicates that the `HttpServletRequest` `inputstream` is empty. Just looking for how I can get this working on a Weblogic 10.3.6 server?

```
@POST
@Path("upload/{environment}/{queueName}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Message putQueueFile(
        @PathParam("environment") String environmentName,
        @PathParam("queueName") String queueName,
        @Context HttpServletRequest req) {

    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {
        log.debug("putQueueFile:: Multipart form submission received");
        // Create a factory for disk-based file items 
        DiskFileItemFactory  fileItemFactory = createDiskFileItemFactory(req.getSession().getServletContext());
        ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);
        uploadHandler.setFileSizeMax(MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE);

        try {
            /*
             * Parse the request
             */
            List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(req);
            log.debug(String.format("putQueueFile:: Looping through %d items", items.size()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of it and it was an issue with the web.xml file we were using for 10.3.  Specifically we had enabled jersey logging for requests with

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This was causing the request to be read and therefore causing an empty input stream. Once the logging for the requests was disabled the error was resolved.